# Constantly scan firestore for new documents get the document ID of it

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am using the Firebase_admin SDK and I want the python script to act as some sort of backend script for my mobile app. Once the user inputs info into the app it updates in Firestore but I need the python script to take that information and do things with it. I have the app and the code for what I want to do with the information, but I need a way to constantly scan for new documents.

Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for realtime updates using the Firestore listen API (available in many languages including Python). Learn more at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen